# Avoid the need to do many service calls

Tags: c#, wcf

I've just started learning WCF.

It seems that every single use of the (remote) classes is translated into a request to the server (even just setting values, before sending them as a parameter to the service).

Doesn't this cause too many unnecessary requests?

What can I do avoid this wasted time & bandwidth? I'm just trying to set some values. The `Set` section of these properties, has nothing but setting the values of the corresponding fields.

For example,

```
interface IService 
{
   int GetResult(MyComplexType1 input);
}
```

To use this service, I must firstly initialize a `MyComplexType1` instance, which makes requests to the server every time I'm setting any value of `MyComplexType1`.

Comment: What are 'remote' classes? Where are some examples of your code?

Comment: Post any sample, or be more specific - what methods? where setting values? etc

Comment: Just creating your `MyComplexType1` and settings its properties is definitely **NOT** a "remote" call - that's something you do locally in your client code. Once you've set up your object, ***then*** you call the web service - that's just **one remote call**

Comment: @marc_s is that so? but if I'm using a method of `MyComplexType1`... does it run locally? how can it be? when adding a web reference, does it copy the content of my methods to the client?

Comment: Data being shipped back and forth with WCF should **never** contain functionality - **only data** (fields/properties) But if it does - then any call will be executed **on the client locally** - WCF **IS NOT** a remote procedure call mechanism

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoking a web service is usually an expensive call in your code, so your design needs to consider that. For example, the following service wouldn't be very effective:

```
public interface ICalculatorService
{
  void SetOperandOne(int value);
  void SetOperandTwo(int value);
  void SetMode(CalculationMode mode);
  int GetResult();
}
```

Whereas the following interface reduces the calls required to one:

```
public interface ICalculatorService
{
  int GetResult(int operandOne, int operandTwo, CalculationMode mode);
}
```